# Flutter adding event to bloc from a callback

Tags: multithreading, flutter, bloc

I'm having an issue where I can't figure out why adding events isn't resulting in the `mapEventToState` method is being called.

When I call `_getFooBar()` I setup an event channel and when it streams changes I want the BLoC to yield new States. But instead only the log gets printed and the `mapEventToState` doesn't get fired.

I'm not sure why the events aren't being added to the BLoC when the lines of code should be executed.

```
Future<void> _getFooBar() async {
    const eventChannel = EventChannel('com.foo.bar/faz');
    
    FazBearBloc bloc = this;

    eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((event) {
      if (event is String) {
        if (event == "foo") {
          dev.log('changes $event');
          bloc.add(FooDidSucceed());
        } else if (event == "bar") {
          dev.log('changes $event');
          bloc.add(FooDidFail());
        }
      }
    }, onError: (error) {
      dev.log('error starting fooBar notifier: ${error}');
    });
}
```

I also tried adding `listen((event) async* {` as the function for the listen method, but the function appears to never happen.

Comment: I think you don't need `await eventChannel`. Also, check if bloc's close method is already called or if bloc is of different type than you are expecting.

Comment: Hmm, I updated the code to remove the await, and show that the`bloc` variable is what I expected. I haven't called `close` on anything, and this is all being called in the bloc itself.

Comment: so are you listening to the plugin inside the bloc? because you have done `FazBearBloc bloc = this`. If that's the case, you can simply use `add` method without having to use `bloc.add` method.

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed what I am doing. I did originally have it without the `bloc.add` and went straight for the `add` method, but that too doesn't trigger the `mapEventToState` method.

Comment: just to be sure, you don't have any transformers in place which might be eating up the event.

Comment: Nope. Ok, I have figured out why it's happening. I'll post the answer now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the widget that has the `BlocProvider` was being dismounted.

So my solution was to make sure the widget wasn't being disposed of.

Comment: I am sorry to comment but dismounting of BlocListener should not hold event to be added to bloc. Widget containing BlocProvider must be getting dismounted as well which result in call to `close` function in bloc.

Comment: Yes! Indeed you are right. I corrected it now. Thanks a lot for your help and feedback, I hugely appreciate it!